# Retrofit2 response on file upload

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I want to upload zip file on myserver. I am using Retrofit2. I have used the following code.

```
private void uploadFile() {
    // create upload service client
    FileUploadService service =
            ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);

    File file = uploadFile;
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-‌urlencoded"),
                    file
            );

    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("fileUpload", file.getName(), requestFile);

    String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
    RequestBody description =
            RequestBody.create(
                    okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);

    Call<JSONObject> call = service.upload(description, body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call,
                               Response<JSONObject> response) {
            System.out.println("UploadFragment.onResponse " + response);
            Log.v("Upload", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Upload error:", t.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

My upload service is like.

```
public interface FileUploadService {

@Multipart
@POST("myurl")
Call<JSONObject> upload(
        @Part("description") RequestBody description,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file
);
```

}

**Problem** When I upload file I get response **{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://myUrl**.
It is not the response returned by my server. How can get my server response?

Answer (score 1):

Its retrofit response. You will get your response in body.

```
response.body().toString();
```

Use this

```
System.out.println("UploadFragment.onResponse " + response.body().toString());
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have tried sending same request using Chrome's advanced rest client. there it has returned the actual response data. But by response.body() it is null.

Comment: Instead of using ```JSONObject``` create actual model then use that.

Comment: Thanks, @Zeeshan, I created model classes and the problem is solved. Got reference from here [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).